# Despite being awaited, Console.Out.WriteLine throwing Exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, asynchronous, console-application

If I uncomment [this line of code](https://github.com/atrauzzi/Gerty/blob/c7b4fa3d5ba098fb0b60ab359debbddca6929c8b/Gerty/Service.cs#L109) in a project of mine, and comment out the one after it, occasionally I'll get the exception & stack trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.CheckState () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.WriteLineAsync (System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.SynchronizedWriter.WriteLineAsync (System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gerty.Service+<PullJob>c__async1.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gerty.Service+<Work>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I guess what's confusing me is that I'm getting this exception despite awaiting the statement.

Comment: *await* provides no guarantee that the process still has a console.  Do use a real logger.

Comment: Agreed, I should get on that right away.  Thanks!  Also: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As things go, using `Console.Out` for debug information is eventually going to interfere with your program.

As of this posting, I feel that [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) is the best option for logging.  Especially in asynchronous applications due to their non-blocking API and very simple configuration.